# Is there a way to insert variables into a string like PHP in C?

Tags: c

Pretty straight forward question, however all search results return C# or C++.
Basically, i'm trying to do something similar to the way PHP handles strings.

```
$var = "hello ". $world;
```

But in C, i did some research and the only thing I found about C says to do something like this:

```
    printf("View a Table's Rows: ");
    scanf("%i", &getTable);

    query = "SELECT * FROM `" += table_names[getTable] += "`";
    if( mysql_query(grab.con, query) ) {

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(grab.con));
        exit(1);

    }
```

That is, to add += the variables into the string.  But this returns errors:

```
m-bin.c: In function 'tables':
m-bin.c:41:8: error: array size missing in 'table_names'
m-bin.c:77:54: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')
```

make: *** [sql] Error 1

Is there a way to do this in C, or am I forced to write my own function to do it?

Edit: getTable is an integer, if that means anything.  Would typecasting help at all, or was I reading an idiots post?

Comment: strcat , snprintf will help.

Comment: Check pit sprintf() you can pass it parameters that will be embedded into the string where you need them. For example: sprintf("Test count:%d, myinteger);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not `sprintf` ?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char buffer [50];
    char var1 [50] = "hello";
    char var2 [50] = "world";

    sprintf(buffer, "%s %s", var1, var2 );

    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: +rep, much appreciated after looking it up it seems I should have figured that out on my own :(.

Still, i'm actually not sure why I got +3 rep for posting this question...

Comment: @IndependentProgrammer: thanks, asking make it faster to you when u learn a new lang

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in C you have to allocate memory and copy the strings to this memory area.

```
char str[100];
strcpy(str, "SELECT * FROM `");
strcat(str, table_names[getTable]);
strcat(str, "`");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `snprintf`

```
int len=strlen("SELECT * FROM `")+strlen(table_names[getTable])+2; //Here 2 for one byte for '`' and one byte for '\0'
char query[len];
snprintf(query,len,"%s%s%c","SELECT * FROM `",table_names[getTable],'`');
printf("%s\n",query);
```